# How do I get the current height of highslide expander

Tags: javascript, highslide

I want to get the current height of the expander, then use

```
var expander = hs.GetExpander();
expander.reflowTo(currentwidth,currenheight+200)
```

and add an extra 200 px to the current height of the expander.

I cannot find a way to retrieve the current height of the expander.

```
hs.height
```

Only returns the original height not the current one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer using prototype JS to select the first child table of the class highslide-container and get it's height. You can use jquery or regular javascript to do the same.

```
$$('.highslide-container table:first-of-type').first().getDimensions().height;
```